# Using System.Threading.Timer to alternate between Async tasks on Discord.net

Tags: c#, discord.net

I'm currently creating a new function for my Discord bot which alternates the Bots playing status. We have some Squad game servers and are pulling the data from Battlemetrics via web.load and using select single nodee from the XPath of the html response.

Now, onto the issue. I have created an async task of update which starts the first threading timer. this then goes to the next async void which starts doing the get request of the information for one server and then once timed out, will run a new threading timer to the next async void to pull the new details.

Now, the issue is this works wonderful for a while, until it starts to completely stop. Is this something I have to change in the threading.timer overloads?

[Code View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vhA63.png)

`_client.Ready += Update;` is what tells the bot, on ready please run the update async task.

```csharp
public async Task Update()
{
    var timer = new System.Threading.Timer(new TimerCallback(FooAsync), null, 2000, Timeout.Infinite);
}
```

This part of code is what is needed (due to being an async task I believe, then to start alternating between the two async voids:

```csharp
public async void FooAsync(Object obj)
{
    var html = @"https://www.battlemetrics.com/servers/squad/9310072";
    HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
    var htmlDoc = web.Load(html);
    // J4F Vars
    var j4f = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/dl/dd[2]/span");
    var j4f1 = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/dl/dd[1]");
    var Status = _client.SetGameAsync($"J4F - Amount of Players: {j4f.InnerText},\n" + $"Current Map:  {j4f1.InnerText},\n", "", ActivityType.Playing);
    await Status;
    var vis = _client.SetStatusAsync(UserStatus.Online);
    await vis;

    var timer = new System.Threading.Timer(new TimerCallback(Next), null, 2000, Timeout.Infinite);
}
```

Number two:

```csharp
public async void Next(Object obj)
{
    var html = @"https://www.battlemetrics.com/servers/squad/9376512";
    HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
    var htmlDoc = web.Load(html);
    // J4F Vars
    var j4f = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/dl/dd[2]/span");
    var j4f1 = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/dl/dd[1]");
    var Status1 = _client.SetGameAsync($"TPA - Amount of Players: {j4f.InnerText},\n" + $"Current Map:  {j4f1.InnerText},\n", "", ActivityType.Playing);
    await Status1;
    var vis1 = _client.SetStatusAsync(UserStatus.Online);
    await vis1;

    var timer = new System.Threading.Timer(new TimerCallback(FooAsync), null, 2000, Timeout.Infinite);
}
```

Comment: This seems like quite a flaky way to do the timers. Why not just have a single timer with a single action, and a boolean flag to indicate if it should run `FooAsync` or `Next`? That way you don't need to constantly recreate the timer object.

Comment: Welcome to SO. I am not entirely sure, but here are my first thoughts: I know that if the execution of a command takes to long, discord will terminate that thread. So consider creating a function that calls `Update()` as a detached Task so that execution can continue

Comment: Hey David! thanks for getting back to me so quick. Would you be able to help with an example? I searched the interwebs and this was the closest possible solution I could find for my idea

Comment: Jakob, Thanks buddy. I will look up some pages on the await

Comment: Yeah you could probably continue using ThreadTimer but I strongly recommend staying with the Tasks module, since this would allow you to only use one Function to implement all the important things. If you want, I can provide a quick example

Comment: Ah so I think I know what you mean now. Where it's on ready execute update, that on ready task eventually gets terminated?

Comment: @JakobTinhofer I would appreciate that please

Comment: Also guys, can you confirm regards to the formatting of the question, was it easy enough to understand my issue and what i'd like to do?

Comment: I meant something like this, much cleaner https://dotnetfiddle.net/qJqUEE

Comment: @DavidG would this work on .net Framework 2.2? Don't shoot me but that's what mine is currently running. Concerned of pushing it up as I'm not sure what discord.net works with atm.

Comment: It's basically the same as your code but with a boolean flag.

Comment: @DavidG Ok, well I have adjusted the code as specified in your example, however... I now get a compile error of cannot await void, would this be a .net framework issue?

Comment: You need to make your `FooAsync` and `Next` methods return `Task`.

Comment: I think that the Tasks need to return a task. Idk if returning the actual task would cause the same issue as in your answer, so maybe return a shorter task that just starts the update task.

Comment: so I have added the return of  return Task.CompletedTask; is this incorrect?

Comment: No, you have an `await` inside the method so there's no need to return anything.

Comment: So, that compiles, however. I'm not seeing it alternate between the two.

Comment: You included the line that flips the boolean value?

Comment: ```        public async Task Update()
        {
            _timer = new Timer(new TimerCallback(WrapperAsync), null, 2000, Timeout.Infinite);

        } ```

Comment: Again, still learning.

Answer (score 0):

Given that `FooAsync` and `Next` are almost identical I'd rewrite like this:

```
public async Task FooAndNextAsync(string url_suffix, string code)
{
    var html = $@"https://www.battlemetrics.com/servers/squad/{url_suffix}";
    HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
    var htmlDoc = web.Load(html);
    // J4F Vars
    var j4f = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/dl/dd[2]/span");
    var j4f1 = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/dl/dd[1]");
    await _client.SetGameAsync($"{code} - Amount of Players: {j4f.InnerText},\n" + $"Current Map:  {j4f1.InnerText},\n", "", ActivityType.Playing);
    await _client.SetStatusAsync(UserStatus.Online);
}
```

Then using a timer is as simple as this:

```
var flag = false;
TimerCallback cb = async _ =>
{
    if (flag = !flag)
        await FooAndNextAsync("9310072", "J4F");
    else
        await FooAndNextAsync("9376512", "TPA");
    flag = !flag;
}
var timer = new System.Threading.Timer(
    new TimerCallback(cb), null,
    TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2.0), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2.0));
```

---

Personally, my preferred approach is to use Microsoft's Reactive Framework and do this instead:

```
var query =
    from i in Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2.0))
    let url_suffix = i % 2 == 0 ? "9310072" : "9376512"
    let code = i % 2 == 0 ? "J4F" : "TPA"
    let htmlDoc = new HtmlWeb().Load($@"https://www.battlemetrics.com/servers/squad/{url_suffix}")
    let j4f = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/dl/dd[2]/span")
    let j4f1 = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/dl/dd[1]")
    from x in Observable.FromAsync(() => _client.SetGameAsync($"{code} - Amount of Players: {j4f.InnerText},\n" + $"Current Map:  {j4f1.InnerText},\n", "", ActivityType.Playing))
    from y in Observable.FromAsync(() => _client.SetStatusAsync(UserStatus.Online))
    select y;
    
IDisposable subscription = query.Subscribe();
```

Stopping the observable subscription is as simple as calling `subscription.Dispose()`.

Comment: So, it complies! However, I think maybe I'm running this on the wrong initialize command because it still won't switch ..

Comment: I feel like I'm missing something really simple here..

Comment: @AshleyJohnson - Did you try the Reactive Framework version?